# How can I test a sinon stub of getView in the then() function when 'this' is changed?

Tags: global-variables, sinon

I want to use sinon to test code in the then() by stub the getView with returns(...). But after calling then(),  "this" is changed, so that the variable "that" also has no stubbed getView any more.

```
    ABC_Class.prototype.Sort = function () {
        var that = this;
        this.doSomething("file_name")
            .then(function (oViewSettingsDialog) {
                that.getView().addDependent(oViewSettingsDialog);
                oViewSettingsDialog.open();
            });
    };
```

The test code:

```
var oView = {
dummy: '1',
addDependent:sandbox.stub().returns(true)
};
sandbox.stub(this.oControllerStub, "getView").returns(oView);
sandbox.stub(this.oControllerStub, "doSomethingForView").returns(Promise.resolve({value:'Resolved', open:sandbox.stub().returns()}));
```

Please help!